# How can I create a fixed floating plus button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm looking to create a floating action button for my mobile application. Similar to the ones used in the Gmail and WhatsApp mobile applications *(see the red button in the image)*.

I'm building a small app using jQuery Mobile and I would like the button to bring the user to another page. I've been researching for quite a while, with mixed results, but the main problem seems to be that the button doesn't sit above all of the other content on the page and doesn't stay fixed in a position once the user scrolls the page.

Does anyone have any resources or knowledge that could assist? Thank you

[image]

Comment: If it stays in a fixed position on the screen that is css `position: fixed` and being on top of all other fields would mean it has a `z-index` larger than anything else on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JQM `footer` has already the `fixed` positioning and the correct `z-index` which plays nicely together with the other JQM widgets, like panels and so on. Why don't use that?

The classes `ui-btn-left` and `ui-btn-right` don't behaves well in `footer`, so I am using a grid with transparent background.  The advantage with this approach is that You can quickly add more buttons, if You need it later.

```css
.ui-footer {
  border-width: 0 !important;
  background: transparent !important; 
}

.ui-grid-d  {
  overflow: visible !important;
  background: transparent !important;
}
.ui-grid-d > .ui-block-a,
.ui-grid-d > .ui-block-b,
.ui-grid-d > .ui-block-c,
.ui-grid-d > .ui-block-d,
.ui-grid-d > .ui-block-e {
  text-align: center !important;
  background: transparent !important;
  padding-top: .3em;
  padding-bottom: .9em;
}

.ui-icon-big {
  height: 40px !important;
  width: 40px !important;
  margin-top: -18px !important;
  border-radius: 20px !important;
}
.ui-icon-big:after {
  width: 32px !important;
  height: 32px !important;
  background-size: 22px !important;
  background-color: #F4123D !important;
  background-color: rgba(244, 18, 61, 0.8) !important;
  margin-top: -16px !important;
  margin-left: -16px !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Jura" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js">
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div data-role="page" id="page-one">
    <div data-role="content">
      <h3>Page content</h3>
      <hr>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
      <div class="ui-grid-d">
        <div class="ui-block-a"></div>
        <div class="ui-block-b"></div>
        <div class="ui-block-c"></div>
        <div class="ui-block-d"></div>
        <div class="ui-block-e">
          <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-icon-plus ui-icon-big ui-btn-icon-notext"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Moreover, You can decide to use `data-tap-toggle="false"` on not (default is true) to allow Your users to show the footer buttons on demand, when the page content is bigger than the screen height.

Answer (score 0):

this is more a CSS question than a JS question although you could use either to solve it.  In CSS that button element or whatever element contains it should have the attributes; position: absolute; and a z-index: x; (a z-index which is higher than any other element in the DOM).  If you try to solve this with JS then you still have to have a z-index property and that only works when and element has a fixed, absolute, or relative position attribute... so you may as well just use CSS. you could use js to determine the hight of the window (the device height on mobile since the browsers are not resize-able like on a desktop) and then set the top: Xpx attribute so that to button appears to be in the same position regardless of the device.

Comment: It would need the `fixed` position, not absolute, for it to stay in the same position while scrolling.  Also you don't need to grab the window height to put it at the bottom of the screen.  You can set the `bottom: 0` for that.

Answer (score 0):

I think this [pen](https://codepen.io/androidcss/pen/yOopGp) would help you. It has a tutorial link.

To make sure that your button is above all other elements, add `z-index: 999` to your button in css.

You can think of `z-index` as layers.
So a `z-index: 2` element will be above a `z-index:1` element.

For further details about the `z-index` css property go [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index).

Answer (score 0):

Here you are:
https://material.io/develop/web/components/buttons/floating-action-buttons/

Read more about it here:
https://material.io/design/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using the "fixed" or "sticky" property values in CSS to hold the image in a relative position to browser window or user's scroll position?

Hope this helps, it's the first idea that comes to mind.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp